# Using savetrees with LuaLaTeX

Tags: spacing, luatex, microtype

Apparently I can't use `savetrees` with `lualatex` - is there another way to expand the writable area to the whole page (for US-letter currently, I think other people are interested in A4)?

I get this error message:

```
! Package microtype Error: The `tracking' feature doesn't currently work
(microtype)                with luatex.
```

Comment: `savetrees` (mine is: v2.0, dated 2011/05/14) should work with `luatex`; if you have found a bug, then it should be reported (or perhaps asked here if you are unsure).

Comment: I added a bit of information to your question, hope you don't mind. (This should make it better-googleable.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `savetrees` with LuaTeX. You just need to load `microtype` with the correct options before loading `savetrees`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[tracking=false]{microtype}
\usepackage{savetrees}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another option, which seems equivalent, is issuing `\microtypesetup{tracking=false}` *after* `\usepackage{savetrees}`. `\PassOptionsToPackage{tracking=false}{microtype}` does *not* work.

Comment: I don't need to deactivate tracking. savetrees works fine for me. I'm using the beta version of microtype `2011/09/05 v2.5 <beta-08>`. It can be found here: http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/ruid=314897842/action=view/id=608